# Octave GNU FFT nested mirrored?

Tags: nested, fft, octave, mirror

I have written a short Octave script for grabbing and summing the individual FFT's of each row in an image. When I plot the summed FFT's, I get the usual FFT mirror from the real values (which is fine), but I also get a secondary nested mirror.  I don't understand why I am getting the nested mirror. The nested mirror has a lower amplitude, but the peak locations have a 1 to 1 correspondence to each other.  Please help me understand why the nested mirror.
[image: FFT nested mirror]

This is what the original image looks like:
[image]
Note that the linked image is downsampled from the original and will not display the behavior shown. I've posted the original image here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhAaA6XQyp6gqp1NgKNqL4QmcMw5Pw?e=P7rdRy

The image is acquired from a Fourier Transform spectrometer. The fringes are the interference pattern of the different wavelengths of light. The spectrum of the light source is derived by doing the FFT.

And finally here is the script:

```
#get image and convert to grayscale...

sum = abs(fftn(gray(1,:))); #get first row FFT and init sum

for i = 2:(rows(gray))
 sum += abs(fftn(gray(i,:))); # add each row FFT together
end;

sum = sum/max(sum); # normalize 0-1 scale
sumHalf = sum(1:(end/2)); # move to single sided FFT
sumHalf = 2*sumHalf;
x = 1:numel(sumHalf);
sumHalf(1) = 0; #removed oversized DC component

semilogy(x,sumHalf); #plot in log scale
```

Comment: @CrisLuego I'm not sure why the right most column is white in the link.  It should not be.  I think the nested mirror is mostly missing because that linked image is super compressed (I didn't even think about image compression when uploading it).  Basically all the high frequency components are compressed out of the linked image.  Let me see if I can upload an uncompressed image somewhere.

Comment: Here is an "uncompressed" link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhAaA6XQyp6gqp1NgKNqL4QmcMw5Pw?e=P7rdRy

Comment: The image is acquired from a Fourier Transform spectrometer. The fringes are the interference pattern of the different wavelengths of light.  The spectrum of the light source is derived by doing the FFT.

Comment: @CrisLuendo So our conversation and your testing on the compressed image got me thinking.  The "nested mirror" is likely a harmonic caused by digitization of the interference pattern. The "steps" caused by both the images sensors pixel resolution and ADC sampling resolution will cause infinite harmonics in the spectrum.

Comment: I does look like there's a sampling at exactly half the camera's sampling frequency going on somewhere in the image formation. I don't have enough knowledge of Fourier transform spectrometers to understand where this would happen. The reduced amplitude of the "nested mirror" is due to the low-pass filtering in the camera, I'm fairly sure.

Comment: PS: Note that you can replace most of your script by this: `s=sum(abs(fft(gray,[],2)),1);` (do be careful to first `clear sum`, since you defined a variable with that name, the function will no longer be available).